# Convex interaction energy

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-optimization

Does anybody know examples of absolutely continuous probability measures $\mu_0,\mu_1$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite 2nd moments such that
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n}|x-y|^2d\mu_t(x) d\mu_t(y)\right)<0,
$$
where $\mu_t=(1-t)\mu_0+t\mu_1$? The inside of the above bracket is known as an interaction energy.

Comment: It is well known that this interaction energy is convex with respect to geodesic interpolation in the quadratic wasserstein distance, so I guess this is quite unlikely. Have you tried an explicit computation with $\mu_0,\mu_1$ two uniform densities on concentric balls but with different radii?

Answer (score 1):

See Leo's comment below. I will construct two discrete probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ for a counterexample.

It seems you can just decompose the measure $\mu_t$ explicitly and expand into three integrals (using symmetry of the integral domain):
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} |x -y|^2 [(1-t)^2d\mu_0(x) d\mu_0(y) + t^2 d\mu_1(x) d\mu_1(y) + 2 t(1-t) d\mu_0(x) d\mu_1(y)].$$
Taking second derivative with respect to $t$, you get:
$$ 2\int |x-y|^2 (d\mu_0(x) d\mu_0(y) + d\mu_1(x) d\mu_1(y) - 2 d\mu_0(x) d\mu_1(y))\\
 = 2 \int |x-y|^2  (d\mu_0(x) - d\mu_1(x))(d\mu_0(y)- d\mu_1(y)).$$

Now let $\nu = \mu_0 - \mu_1$ be the signed measure above. I can take $\nu$ to be the following discrete signed probability on $\{1,-1\} \subset \mathbb{R}$: $\nu(-1) = -1/2$, $\nu(1) = 1/2$. Then the last integral becomes 
$$\sum_{x \in \{\pm 1\}} \sum_{y \in \{\pm 1\}} |x-y|^2 \nu(x)\nu(y) = 2 * 4 * (-1/4) = -2 < 0.$$

To construct $\nu$, simply take $\mu_0(1) = 3/4$, $\mu_0(-1) = 1/4$ and $\mu_1(1) = 1/4$, $\mu_1(-1) = 3/4$, and verify that $\nu = \mu_0 - \mu_1$.

Comment: The OP wanted absolutely continuous measures (w.r.t Lebesgue, I guess). But taking any of one's favourite approximation should do the trick.

Comment: @leo: Indeed. I learned from the masters to always look for counterexamples in the Bernoulli case.